# MySQL query to search for closest highest number

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table

```
+------------+------------+--------------+---------------+
|    lbs     |     tx     |      ca      |       ny      |
+------------+------------+--------------+---------------+
|     1      |     20     |      30      |       40      |
+------------+------------+--------------+---------------+
|     2      |     25     |      35      |       45      |
+------------+------------+--------------+---------------+
|     3      |     30     |      40      |       50      |
+------------+------------+--------------+---------------+
```

I want MySQL query to get closest highest number based on two variables. Something like

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE state = '$state' AND lbs = '$lbs' NEAREST HIGHEST
```

As in input of 1.3 lbs selects 2 lbs

is this possible?

Comment: I don't understand, what do you mean by nearest highest. What data do you want to store in the table? How is it organized?

Comment: min where greater than ( or greater than or equal to )

Comment: Greatest of nearest two values

Comment: there is no column called state

Comment: KTAnj, that is the problem. I need to find how can I query variable column

Comment: @e342 Do you have any idea , what is the out put?

Comment: @KTAnj in php $lbs is input field, $state is dropdown option.

When you select lbs and state, it should output the number that corresponds with closest greatest lbs AND state

Comment: Ok , then I have no idea that which column is matched with the selected state?

Comment: @e342  I'm not clear about state, but try this. `SELECT min( lbx ) AS lbx, tx, ca, ny
FROM table
WHERE lbx >= 1.3`

Comment: I have a bunch of states, each one of them in its own column, but on the same row. I have over 300 'lbs' values on the left in one column. Each pair of 'state' and 'lbs' should give out different value written in MySQL. How can I make it? I do not believe I am the only one facing this challenge

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Very simple :

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE state = '$state' AND lbs >= '$lbs' LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Great solution, but I have no column called "state". How can I get MySQL value from variable column?

Comment: $query2 = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE " . '$state' . " = '$state' AND lbs >= '$expressMax' LIMIT 1";

Apparently for many people on the net it is viable solution, but it doesn't work for me..

Comment: It doesn't matter anymore. I will make loads of else if's. Your query works great!